# python code errors in while loop and if else

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

I don't know why it is not working there are no errors or warnings it was suppossed to multiply by 3 and add 1 if the number in odd and if the number is even it is supposed to divide by 2 until it reaches 0
here is my code any help will be appreciated

```
    num = 4
while num != 0:
    if num % 2 == 1:
        num = (num * 3) + 1
    else:
        num /= 2
```

Comment: You cannot reach 0 with a finite number of divisions. Your code will run indefinitely, even if you had the right criterion. But checking `if num % 2 == 1` will only ever get you down to 1, at which point you get back to 4 and are stuck in a loop anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop wil run indefinitely because num wil never be 0. I think you want `num != 1`.  look at this wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture, And specificly the picture, you can see that 0 is never reached.

Comment: thanks robin for your help i am new in python so i didn't knew it